# git branching with stripped down versions of software

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

currently I work on a role where we need to strip down features of the software. The company I work for decided to use different branches (I suggested feature toggle as the software is modular but they want branches).

So we got our develop branch. Now we created branch A for client A. Branch A should contain all features of the software and they recommended we strip develop branch so that we can deploy a stripped version for client B.

I find the above problematic as it won't be easy to merge fixes to A again. So I recommended we have develop, A and B branches. Develop is our single source of truth with all features. B is stripped down.

Is there a better approach?